# Are you using your VPS' bandwidth when using it as VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, bandwidth, openvpn

I setup my VPS from a different country as an OpenVPN Access Server. I am now connecting to it from my PC using OpenVPN client. If I download 1GB of data to my PC while connected to the VPN, is my VPS also effectively transferring 1GB of bandwidth to my PC? To illustrate further, is this what's actually happening?

`Website <---1GB Bandwidth---> VPS (used as VPN) <---1GB Bandwidth---> My PC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.  The VPN system (regardless of whether it's run on a VPS, or on a dedicated hardware system (like a VPN concentrator) basically works like this:

1) you establish a secured VPN "tunnel" to that server (or router).  All traffic that you configure (and the simplest case is to tunnel everything) will go from your machine to the VPN server.

2) the VPN server then has a connection to either a corporate network, or to "the internet".

So your drawing is correct.  To measure bandwidth, let's take a contrived example where all you do is send a 100kB request to the server (while connected to the VPN), and then the server responds with 1MB of data.  So in your picture above you've sent 100kB of data from "right to left" and you've sent 1MB of data from "left to right".

DEPENDING on how exactly your VPS provider bills for bandwidth, you could be billed/accounted for 100k, or 1MB, or 1.1MB.  (I don't actually know whether it's most common for VPS providers to bill bi-directionally or only for one direction, but I'd assume it's bidirectionally...)

Comment: Somehow I've got the feeling that that billing was what he was really asking about... I was typing a similar answer but you were quicker.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was billing also, but I just can't resist the chance to over-generalize an answer when it's so damn easy.  ;)

Comment: I know the feeling :-)